# sending data with history.goBack()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i am working on a MERN stack app. When the user registers i want to redirect him to the log in page and show him an alert on the log page. To redirect i am using the react `{useHistory}` however when i send data from signup using the `history.goBack({data})`, nothing happens...[image: code screenshot]

this is the code in the signup
this is the login where i console.log the history
[image: developer tools inspector screenshot]

Comment: are you sure `history.goBack` take arguments?

Comment: nope, i am not sure

Comment: Please show all relevant code, data, and errors as text, not as a picture of text.

Comment: `history.goBack()` does not accept any params. Set the data in cookies and read the cookies after going back to the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass data into the `goBack()` method.

Instead, set a query param and then on the other page look if it's present and use it.

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/test',
  search: '?foo=bar',
})
```

And to get it (native way):

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
const foo = params.get('foo'); // bar
```